# Retaining payment information on admin order form

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, orders, payment

We use admin order form for phone orders.  One thing that can be a pain is that if the customer makes changes to the order, after we enter the payment information, we must ask them for their payment information and enter it again.

Is there any way to allow the payment information to be retained by the form while we are still editing the order (shipping choices, add/remove product, etc.) ?

I'm not looking to store the card information with the customer, I just want to avoid reentering the information if customer changes mind before I click "Submit Order."

Comment: FYI... I'm not looking to credit-card gateway 'tokenization' as a solution, was just hoping that the implementation could retain those field values until order is submitted.

Comment: I've been told by developers that is just the way the Magento "work flow" works for that form, if you go back to an earlier step (adding items) it clears the payment fields.